# Checking if a "distinct_id" already exists in Mixpanel Javascript

Tags: javascript, mixpanel

Is there a way to check to see if a previous "distinct_id" already exists in Mixpanel with Javascript?

I am currently having an issue where once someone moves through my onboarding process and all the events are tracked, if they log out and log back in it is creating a separate record in the "explore" section of the admin interface.

I want to be able to throw some logic around my initial login event to make sure to check if the "Distinct_id" already has been used, and then tie the login event to that same user instead of creating a brand new one in Mixpanel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be great to see your code, but I can guess the following answer based on my experience:

The first time you create a people profile, you should create it executing `mixpanel.alias(YOUR_DISTINCT_ID)` instead of `mixpanel.identify()`. This will associate the mixpanel internal distinct_id with your custom distinct id (for instance: an email address, an username, etc).

Next time the user lands on a different page, you call `mixpanel.identify(YOUR_DISTINCT_ID)`.

Doing so, if the user logs out, and then logs in back, calling `mixpanel.identify(YOUR_DISTINCT_ID)` will be enough, Mixpanel is going to associate your custom id with the original one avoiding duplicated profiles.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up having to do. My problem was that in my flow when the user logged back in after logging out it was always calling "alias", so like you said I just made a change to check to see if it was the first time they had ever logged in or not, and if they had already called "identify" instead. One thing to note is that I did have to add "mixpanel.cookie.clear()" to when my user does a logout, because if I tried to log back in with a different user on the same device it would overwrite that user in Mixpanel.