# creating a profile with mixpanel to track users not working

Tags: mixpanel

I installed mixpanel yesterday and I'm struggling to create new profiles of my users. I have managed to track events and forms, so I can track when someone completes the registration form, for example. I don't understand how to use this to then identify my users?

What I think I understand from the documentation here: https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/creating-a-profile is that I need to identify the users. But where am I getting that id from?

Essentially, what I want is that when someone completes the registration form, that is tracked, but it also identifies them as a new user and creates their profile on mixpanel. This is how far I've managed to get in my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  mixpanel.track_forms("#register", "Created Account");
  mixpanel.identify()
</script>
```

Obviously, the .identify is not doing anything yet. Any help on how to make it work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if a "distinct\_id" already exists in Mixpanel Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28924074/checking-if-a-distinct-id-already-exists-in-mixpanel-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

The manual on this topic is on this page: https://mixpanel.com/docs/integration-libraries/using-mixpanel-alias

1. Identify method must be fired before track method.
2. If you have registration on your website the Alias method must be used instead Identify.

Answer (score 1):

What mechanism do you have to identify a user uniquely across your web application ?. 
It is usually suggested to use mixpanel.identify(email_id). But be careful with this approach, If user can change their email id on your web app, You would end up having two user profile against a same user on mixpanel. Best way to avoid such scenarios is to use "user_id" against which you save user details in your DB.

Answer (score 1):

For using identify function of mixpanel you need to have unique id of your own to track every activities of the user. It can be the primary key of the user like username, email id which is unique.
Now what you must do is

```
mixpanel.alias('uniqueKey');
mixpanel.identify();
mixpanel.people.set({
   'username': username,
   'email': email
});
```

Remember that `mixpanel.alias` must be used only once when user registers in the system points your uniquekey to the mixpanel autogenerated distinct id. 
Calling identify() with no parameters will use the default distinct_id.
Only when existing users log in should you call
`mixpanel.identify(uniquekey );`
And the last one `mixpanel.people.set()` stores user profile to mixpanel which you can view in explore tab. This function takes json which you can pass anything you like to store.